# printing integers as characters, decimals, floats

Tags: c

Let me start by saying that I am brand new to programming.  I am a math major and I don't know very much about the computer programming world.  That said, my assignment wants me to enter an integer and print it out as the corresponding ASCII character, decimal, float.  I am ok going from a character to the corresponding integer, but the reverse has me puzzled.  Please help!

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main (void)
    {
        char E = 'E';
        char e = 'e'; 
        char D = 'D';
        char d = 'd';
        int m;

    printf("\nPlease enter an integer : ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    printf("\nThe number as a character is : %c", E, e, D, d);

    return 0;
}  // main
```

This is what I have so far, but I know it's wrong.

Comment: `printf("\nThe number as a character is : %c", m);` You ar doing it the right way, you have just to print the number as a character.
But you should first check, if the input is in right range: 65-122

Comment: Your printf is actually wrong, there is just one format specifier (%c) for 4 arguments.

Comment: be careful when using float, you need the cast there....

Comment: its not really clear what the requirement is. Print an integer as a float. Does that mean enter 1 and print 1.0. Or does it mean 'see what happens if you try to persuade this c compiler that a int in memory is really a float'. These are two entirely different things, both of questionable value :-). Also C doesnt have the concept 'decimal'

Comment: did the prof show an example of the expected output for , say, 42?

Comment: thank you, I didn't realize all these comments were going to come in under my math page so I am just seeing them now.

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure what you want to achieve.

`printf` will treat a parameter as a type you want using % format specifier.

So if you have entered some value which is interpreted as signed decimal integer you can print it treating as a different type with the `printf` function.

If you want your `m` variable being printed as character do:

`printf("The number as a character is %c", m);`

If you want to display it as a `float`, use `%f`.

Here is some reference:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: So it just gives me the letter A and not the one corresponding to the integer in the ASCII table.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking at the `printf` formats

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int m;

    printf("Please enter an integer : ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    printf("The number as a character is : '%c' %02X %o %d %f", m, m, m, m, (float) m);

    return 0;
}
```